# Checkbox binding in php

Tags: php, knockout.js

I want to accomplish checkbox binding in php.I have written following code for fetching the data from the database:

```
$result = mysql_query("select * from users where kunnr='".$_SESSION["kunnr"]."'");
if(isset($page["id"]))
{
    $result = mysql_query("select * from users where kunnr='".$_SESSION["kunnr"]."' and id='".$page["id"]."'");
}
$model['check']=array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    array_push($model['check'],
        array(
            "id"=>$row["id"],
            "active"=>$row["active"],
            "admin"=>$row["admin"],
            "web"=>$row["web"],
            "mstudio"=>$row["mstudio"],
            "projectcentral"=>$row["projectcentral"],
            "icenter"=>$row["icenter"],
            "sales"=>$row["sales"],
            "prospect_admin"=>$row["prospect_admin"],
            "default_contact"=>$row["default_contact"],
            "no_acts"=>$row["no_acts"],
            "no_daily"=>$row["no_daily"],
            "sync_exchange"=>$row["sync_exchange"]

        ));
}
```

and inside the view which is the different file is as follows:

```
<tbody data-bind="foreach: items" style="height:113px;">
                    <tr>
                        <td><a href="#" class="projectslink" data-bind="attr: {value: id, title: question}, text:question"></a></td>
                        <td><input type="checkbox" disabled data-bind="value: id, checked: active=='true'"/></td>
                        <td><input type="checkbox" disabled data-bind="value: id, checked: required=='true'"/></td>
<td><input type="checkbox" disabled data-bind="value: id, checked: required=='true'"/></td>
<td><input type="checkbox" disabled data-bind="value: id, checked: required=='true'"/></td>
<td><input type="checkbox" disabled data-bind="value: id, checked: required=='true'"/></td>
<td><input type="checkbox" disabled data-bind="value: id, checked: required=='true'"/></td>
                    </tr>
```

so kindly suggest me...

Comment: Can you please post also your KO code, so your ViewModel's definition?

Comment: $(function(){
    var refreshMyModel=function(data){
        ko.applyBindings(new DynamicModel(data.projects), document.getElementById("projectsTable"));
        ko.applyBindings(new DynamicModel(data.service), document.getElementById("serviceTable"));
    };
    var refreshMyList=function(){
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: root+"data/data?json",
            success: refreshMyModel,
            dataType: "json"
        })
    };

Comment: You didn't post your ViewModel within that javascript code.